# Multiple QA Environments in SItecore

Tags: sitecore

Currently we have one QA Sitecore environment which is replica of production environment to host the version of master code branch. We need to branch out a code base for a new project. Can we use the same QA environment to have these two branches, meaning, we should have environment to test any production issues and test new project as well.

Is it possible in Sitecore as everything is driven thru integrated DB mode?

We are using TFS and TDS for development and build process.

Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

Mani, I would not recommend using the same Sitecore website and database for two different branches that are being maintained.  I am assuming you have only a single license for your QA environment, which is why you are attempting to push everything through the same environment.

Your ideal setup should have a separate database and separate IIS website running for new development work, to allow you the opportunity to maintain your production site from your production code branch in your existing QA environment, and then use a development branch for your development work.

That being said, if you are delivering new functionality to production every few weeks, you can probably do both on a single stream of code and just regularly push out to production both new work and maintenance work.  That is usually an unlikely setup for most organizations, though.

If you must have only one Sitecore installation running at a time due to license restrictions, what I would recommend doing is creating both website folders and both databases, but only operating a single website at a time.  You could toggle between them in IIS by switching which folder your IIS site is pointing at.  By operating only a single instance, you should meet your licensing restrictions.

That being said, I'm not a lawyer, nor a Sitecore licensing expert, so I would follow up with your sales rep to see if that approach would meet your needs.